# Mobile Push: Bulk-upload geofence locations

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

a customer has more than 100 locations. Is there a way to bulk upload the geolocations to use them as entry locations for a mobile push? Or do I have to set them manually.

Thanks!
Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered calling the MobilePush APIs to accomplish this?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm

Comment: That's it. Thanks. Sometimes the things are hard to find ;-)